# wpp.targets to change folder permissions - only first folder permissions are applied

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-ec2, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am deploying to elastic beanstalk via Visual Studio 2013.

Here is my wpp.targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest"> 
   <ItemGroup>
     <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
       <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\ChatFiles</Path>
       <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
       <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
       <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
     </MsDeploySourceManifest>
     <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl"> 
           <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\FileHoldingForS3</Path>
            <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess> 
           <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType> 
            <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings> 
        </MsDeploySourceManifest>
     <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
       <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\FileHoldEmail</Path>
       <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
       <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
       <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
     </MsDeploySourceManifest>
         </ItemGroup> 
 </Target> 
 <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems"> 
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="FilesSetAclParam">
        <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
        <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
        <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\ChatFiles$</Match>
        <Description>Add write permission to the ChatFiles folder.</Description>
        <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/ChatFiles</DefaultValue>
        <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/ChatFiles</Value>
        <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
        <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
        <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="FilesSetAclParam">
           <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind> 
             <Scope>setAcl</Scope> 
            <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\FileHoldingForS3$</Match>
            <Description>Add write permission to the FileHoldingForS3 folder.</Description> 
             <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/FileHoldingForS3</DefaultValue> 
             <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/FileHoldingForS3</Value> 
            <Tags>Hidden</Tags> 
            <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority> 
            <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter> 
       </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="FilesSetAclParam">
        <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
        <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
        <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\FileHoldEmail$</Match>
        <Description>Add write permission to the FileHoldEmail folder.</Description>
        <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/FileHoldEmail</DefaultValue>
        <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/FileHoldEmail</Value>
        <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
        <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
        <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
    </ItemGroup> 
 </Target>
```

But only the folder permissions for the first folder is applied.

I am ensuring that I the wpp.targets file is not cached prior to deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't instruct MSDeploy to ignore ACLs via the MSDeploy.exe call

```
,includeAcls="False"
```

Or in the build:

http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/skipping-setting-an-acl-in-a-visual-studio-2010-deployment-package

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that for each:

```
  MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="FilesSetAclParam"
```

The FilesSetAclParam should be unique for each one (of course!)